# Is Password transmitted securely using DirectoryEntry

Tags: .net, authentication, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

I am reviewing code that authenticates user credentials against an LDAP server by creating a `DirectoryEntry` object as follows

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

try
{
    object obj = entry.NativeObject;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
}
```

If an exception is not thrown then the code assumes that the user credentials are ok..

The code works fine but my questions relates to how secure it is. SSL is used so the communication between client and web server is secure but is there a vulnerability in the communication between webserver and ldap server?

There is another overloaded parameter to the `DirectoryEntry` constructor called `AuthenticationType`. Because no parameter is specified in the above code it uses `AuthenticationType = None` which equates to basic authentication.

Would it be better to use `AuthenticationType = Secure` or `AuthenticationType = SecureSocketsLayer` or `AuthenticationType = Encryption` or maybe a bitwise combination of them?

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default AuthenticationType.Secure is used when AuthenticationType is not provided in the constructor. This option already encrypts the password, as it uses NTLM/Kerberos for authentication.

You may also specify the Sealing flag (together with Secure) to encrypt all the traffic (not just authentication). This requires Kerberos.

Is the LDAP server you are connecting to an AD?
I verified that the above works for AD.
(traffic are encrypted, as seen in wireshark)

Comment: I tried setting Secure,Sealing,Encryption to bind a secured DirectoryEntry; But I face exception "The server is unwilling to process the request."; Cant I use all 3 types together?

Comment: Never tried putting all 3 together. But by only Secure+Sealing the traffic is already encrypted and verified integrity (by cryptographic checksum). What do you want to achieve actually for adding the Encryption flags?

Comment: By setting 2 flags, if its already encrypted, then its ok for me;